# How to capture List of Processes that have received SIGSEGV

Tags: c, linux, signals

Part of my application (preferably a daemon)  required to log the list of process names that have got core dumped. It would be great, if someone points which mechanism that I can use?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible without modification to the OS. Linux, I assume? I don't know if it keeps track of this anyway, but it might involve modifying the handler for SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the processes are truly dumping core, you could use the following trick:

Set `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to `|/absolute/path/to/some/program %p %e`

This will cause the system to execute your program (with the faulting process' pid and executable name), and pipe the core dump into its standard input. You may then log and store the core dump file.

Note that the program will run as the user and group `root`

See [`man 5 core`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/5/core/) for more information, and an example core dump handling program